# Unknown symbol in result from Redis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I take all rows from `Redis Set` using query:

```
all = r.smembers("apps")
```

Then I do:

```
for url in all:
   print(url)
```

In output `print` console I get:

```
b'https://go.com/e/s/details?id=meinepilze.mp\r\n'
```

What is symbol `b` in the beginning of line?

How can I get clear link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: And how to remove it?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string/606199#606199) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `bytes` object or better a 'not' decoded string.
If you want a simple `str` just use

```
>>> b'string'.decode('utf-8')
'string'
```

for your case it would be

```
for url in all:
    print(url.decode('utf-8'))
```